# fuser doesn't show the PID of the process with open file

Tags: linux, filesystems, process, ubuntu-16.04

I just opened my `.bashrc` in `vim` and ran

```
$ fuser .bashrc
$
```

But there is no output, even though `vim` had this file open in another terminal.

`-m` option works but shows ALL processes accessing files on the file system where `.bashrc` exists.

But I want to know the processes that only have this specific file(`.bashrc` in my example) open, which is `vim` in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't see anything if `vim` only opened the file, read it, then closed it.
For `fuser` to find `vim`, the file must be kept open.

You might compare with these methods for listing processes using a file,
whichever are available for your distribution:

- Use [lsof](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html):

  ```
  lsof <filename>
  ```
- Use `/proc`:

  ```
  find /proc -regex '\/proc\/[0-9]+\/fd\/.*' -type l -lname "filename" -printf "%p -> %l\n" 2> /dev/null
  ```

Comment: The file was indeed open in `vim` in another terminal. What do you mean when you say `vim` closed it? Is there any other close than the manual close we are referring to?

Comment: I don't know exactly how vim works, but what you are seeing may be a copy of the file. Compare using the other utilities, to find out.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it was the problem with the way vim opens a file. I wrote a standalone C program that `open`s the file and just sleeps for a long time. Both `lsof` and `fuser` work fine.